# Calculate gradient problem

Tags: machine-learning, gradient-descent

\begin{align*}
score_k(x)&=w_kx+ b_k\forall k\in {\{1,,,k\}}\\
P(k|x)&=\frac{score_k(x_i)}{\sum_{k'}score_{k'}(x_i)}\\
E_i&=-logP(y_i|x_i)\\
\frac{\partial E_i}{\partial w_k}&=??
\end{align*}
I'm trying to solve this problem. I knew that I should use chain rule.
So I figured out
$$\frac{\partial E_i}{\partial w_k}=\frac{\partial E_i}{\partial P_k}\frac{\partial P_k}{\partial score_k(x)}\frac{\partial score_k(x)}{\partial w_k}$$
I knew $$\frac{\partial score_k(x)}{\partial w_k}=x$$
but I can't solve the others. Thank you.